# For-loop issue involving arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, metadata

I am trying to make a for-loop that is based on simulated metadata.

**Data** is representing the data contents.

**Meta** is representing 3 different metadata types. If there is a 1 it means the meta is present in the data, if there is a 0 it means it is not present.

**Size** represents the size of each data if the metadata is present. So if there is metadata of *1 1 1* with the size of 3:

- That represents meta 1 first 3 elements in the array, meta 2 next 3 elements in the array, meta 3 next 3 elements in array.

The problem I am having is correctly reading it in sequential order from left to right, and if it runs out of data not to create new one, just stop reading from the array.

If we have a data of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and meta of 1, 1, 1, size 1 it should be:

Meta 1: 1

Meta 2: 2

Meta 3: 3

Or if it was data of [1, 2, 3 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] and a meta of 1, 0, 1, size 4, it should be:

Meta 1: 1 2 3 4

Meta 2: Nothing

Meta 3: 5 6 7 8

> What I have so far:

```js
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let meta = [1, 0, 1];
let size = 4;

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (meta[i]) {
      if (i == 0) {
          console.log('Meta', 1);
          for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
              console.log(data[i]);
          }
      }
      if (i = 1) {
        console.log('Meta', 2);
        for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
              console.log(data[i] + size);
          }
      }
      if (i = 2) {
        console.log('Meta', 3);
         for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
              console.log(data[i] + size + size);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) is your friend

Comment: @zer00ne I forgot about length, I guess I am just having issues with the logic part.

Comment: You can use a condition like this: `i < Math.min(data.length, (size * i) + i)` for the inner loops. Here the first `i` is the variable defined in the outer loop, you should use different variable names.

Comment: The outer loop should run the length of data which should give you enough iterations to complete whatever that you're doing (very confusing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove your inner if-statements as they are duplications and instead use the variable `i` to print the `i`<sup>th</sup> plus one's meta value.

In the snippet below I have created a variable `j` which is used to keep track of which point in the data we're at. This is used to jump in segments of `size` when each `meta` is found.

Then in the inner for loop I loop from `j` to `j+size` which is a particular portion of your `data` array of length `size`.

See example below:

```js
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let meta = [1, 0, 1];
let size = 4;

let j = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < meta.length; i++) {
  console.log('Meta', i+1);
  if (meta[i]) {
      for(let k = j; k < j+size && k < data.length; k++) {
        console.log(data[k]);
      }
      j+=size;
  } else {
    console.log("-- Nothing --");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a really good answer also, it is the math part I always have trouble with.

Comment: This still doesn't prevent the inner loop from going beyond `data.length`

Comment: @Titus what do you mean by that exactly? I was also found this example useful because it was easily transferable to C++.

Comment: You don't need `j` you can just do `k < Math.min(data.length, ((i + 1) * size) + k)`

Comment: @Titus is it technically the same with using J as a variable instead of `k < Math.min`?

Comment: @Raymond I mean that the inner loop's condition is `k < j+size` and there is nothing stopping `k` from getting bigger then `data.length`.

Comment: @Titus When I just tested it with a higher data length, I noticed what you meant. It went out of bounds in the for loop.

Comment: I added an additional clause to the for loop, hopefully that fixes it

Comment: @Titus yeah, you're right about not needing `j`, nice idea :D

Comment: Yes, but thinking about it, using a variable makes this easier to read, without that, beside changing the loops condition you'll also have to change the definition of `k` to something like `let k = size * i`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in following steps:

- Create a function which takes `data`,`meta` and `size` as three parameters.
- Create an empty array which will the result.
- Then loop over the `meta` array.
- Then get the part of the array from start equal to size of array. And `push()` that into result array.
- Remove the added part from original array.
- At last return result

```js
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let meta = [1, 0, 1];
let size = 4;
function parts(data,meta,size){
  let res = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<meta.length;i++){
    res.push(data.slice(0,size * meta[i]));
    data = data.slice(meta[i] * size);
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(parts(data,meta,size))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I wish I could accept two answers, I remember you helping me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to take `slice`s of size `size` from `data` if the meta flag is true. You should be able to do that by simply looping over `meta` while keeping track of your current spot in data:

```js
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let meta = [1, 0, 1];
let size = 4;
let res = [];

for (let i = 0, cur = 0; i < meta.length; i++){
    res.push(data.slice(cur, cur + size * meta[i]))
    cur += size * meta[i]
}
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response, this is a logical approach.